# Printer prints 2 extra copies

Tags: printer, printing

When the user prints one copy - one copy comes out.  When they print 2 copies, 4 come out.  When they print 3 copies, 5.  When they print 4 copies, 4 come out.

Dell 5310n printer, tried multiple driver versions.

Only happens on one particular machine.  Other identical machines running the same image, printing to the same printer do not have this issue. (Windows XP SP3)

This applies to all programs tested.  Word, Excel, Firefox.

Has been going on for weeks.  Resetting the machine/printer has no effect.

Comment: Have you looked at the printer options on the affected machine?

Comment: Sure, what did you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the computer had some printer preferences set to make more than one copy on print.